# Why does request.getRemoteAddr().equals("127.0.0.1") when accessing from a remote machine

Tags: java, security, servlets, httprequest

I have a Java servlet application running within Tomcat, there is one admin command that I only want to be able to run from the machine itself (or possibly my own pc as well) for security reasons. So to enforce this I check the remote address of the HttpServletRequest that I receive but **it always returns 127.0.0.1 even though the request is not coming from the local host**

Why is this, can I fix it or is there an alternative way to run my admin command only from the server.

Comment: Can you please paste some of your code and explain where are you trying to perform this check?

Comment: is there something in front of the tomcat on the machine it is running on (e.g. nginx) that forwards the request? Try taking a look at the 'X-Forwarded-For' header.

Comment: @Jonas Adler, thanks yes the x-forwarded-for value when I run from the server as opposed to my homepc is different (although the value when I run from my home pc doesnt match my home pcs ipaddress) so I guess I should check on x-forwarded-for value instead and restrict access to my server machine.

Comment: @Robert Sever I do the check within my main (and only) Servlet, which is referenced in my web.xml servlet-mapping section.

Comment: The 'X-Forwarded-For' header is set by instances that forward the Request to your server (proxies, load balancers). Try and find out what forwards your request.

Comment: @Jonas Adler for what purpose, i.e this is a remote server not setup by me that I rent, using 'X-Forwarded-For' works for me so is there any point, is there something that I should request the administrator changes ?

Comment: If that works for you it should be fine. Have a look at the wiki: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). Note that the header can hold more than one address. The first one should always be the one you're looking for.

Comment: If you add an actual answer Ill mark it as correct, just read the wiki   and slightly confused if it saying that the request has come from a proxy, or that access to my server is only through a proxy

Comment: I guess that has something to do with your provider's setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if the request has the 'X-Forwarded-For' header. If the header is set, the first IP in it should be the one you're looking for. If the header is empty `request.getRemoteAddr()` should return the correct IP.

Wiki for 'X-Forwarded-For': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Note that you cannot be 100% sure that you get the correct IP like this since forwarding instances are not forced to set the 'X-Forwarded-For' header.